# Serialize a list of optionals with kotlinx serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

How can I stringify a list of optional strings with kotlinx serialization? I would like to execute something similar to:

```
val json = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable)
val data: List<String?> = listOf("v1", null, "v3")
val dataJson = json.stringify(String.serializer().list, data)
```

However, this does not compile. I understand that `String.serializer().list` provides a `SerializationStrategy<List<String>>` where I need a `SerializationStrategy<List<String?>>`. How can I acquire the latter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NullableSerializer`:

```
val dataJson = json.stringify(NullableSerializer(String.serializer()).list, data)
println(dataJson) // prints ["v1",null,"v3"]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated!